# Which levels of Amazing Breaker can I get x20 and x25 chain reactions?

Tags: achievements, ios, amazing-breaker

I've been playing [Amazing Breaker](http://www.amazingbreaker.com/) recently and saw there are achievements for chain reaction x20 and x25. For a chain of 25 I believe you need 9 Split Bombs or Helicopter Bombs - or perhaps 8 of them (24 sub-bombs) plus a detonation.

But I haven't noticed any levels with the possibility of that number of bombs. Is it possible to get those achievements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing all the levels again, I found that **level 45** will allow you to get the Chain Reaction x20 achievement. You start with 3 split bombs and 2 spike bombs, but there are chances to get another 2 split bombs and 2 helicopter bombs, a total of 21 "sub-bombs" if you play it right. (Hint: shoot the split bombs off to the side and use the spike bombs to pick up the bonus bombs.)

UPDATE: with the latest batch of levels released, the x25 chain reaction achievement is now possible, via **level 87**. (I assume getting the x25 here will also give you the x20 but I haven't tested.)

Answer (score 1):

Its easy on Stage 5 Level 87, just switch to the green split bombs and shoot both of them onto the board first, then blow the whole thing up and it will be a 25 chain.